# how to synchronize between cuda kernel function?

Tags: cuda, synchronize

I have two cuda kernel functions like this

```
a<<<BLK_SIZE,THR_SIZE>>>(params,...);
b<<<BLK_SIZE,THR_SIZE>>>(params,...);
```

After function a started, I want to wait until a finishes and then start function b.
so I inserted cudaThreadSynchronize() between a and b like this,

```
a<<<BLK_SIZE,THR_SIZE>>>(params,...);
err=cudaThreadSynchronize();
if( err != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaThreadSynchronize error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
b<<<BLK_SIZE,THR_SIZE>>>(params,...);
```

but cudaThreadSynchronize() returns error code: `the launch timed out and was terminated cuda error`

how can I fix it?

---

A simple code explanation:

```
mmap(sequence file);
mmap(reference file);

cudaMemcpy(seq_cuda, sequence);
cudaMemcpy(ref_cuda,reference);

kernel<<<>>>(params); //find short sequence in reference
cudaThreadSynchronize();
kernel<<<>>>(params);

cudaMemcpy(result, result_cuda);
report result
```

and in kernel function, there is a big for loop which contains some if-else for the pattern matching algorithm to reduce number of comparisons.

Comment: In Nvidia's CUDA forum (eg, [cuda the launch timed out and was terminated](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=189042) ), people are pointing to kernels that take too long to run on the GPU which is also being used for your video display. The solution is to shorten the kernel or to use different GPU (eg, integrated graphics) to drive your display.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This launch error means that something went wrong when your first kernel was launched or maybe even something before that. To work your way out of this, try checking the output of all CUDA runtime calls for errors. Also, do a cudaThreadSync followed by error check after all kernel calls. This should help you find the first place where the error occurs.

If it is indeed a launch failure, you will need to investigate the execution configuration and the code of the kernel to find the cause of your error.

Finally, note that it is highly unlikely that your action of adding in a cudaThreadSynchronize caused this error. I say this because the way you have worded the query points to the cudaThreadSynchronize as the culprit. All this call did was to catch your existing error earlier.

Comment: i checked all kernel calls before calling a, but there was no error.
then "the launch timed out and was terminated cuda error" could be occured during function a??

Comment: Enc: Yes, there must be something wrong with kernel a. Either its execution configuration or what you are doing inside its kernel.

Comment: thanks Ashwin. is there any guess about this situation?? i have no idea which one causes this problem. One thing i recognize is that when i use small data(~10 MBs), it works well but i use larger data(few hundreds MBs, but fit in memory on graphic card), it doesn't work.

Comment: Enc: It might be helpful if you share a bit of the kernel code in the question.

Comment: my code is basically pattern matching which reports how many times "short sequence" appears in long "reference".

Comment: Enc: This is not helpful unless you share the execution configuration when you launch the kernel and the code of the kernel itself.